# How to use camera as a texture in OpenGL ES?

Tags: opengl-es, camera, textures, augmented-reality

I'm undertaking a Augment Reality project in Android platform,which to do something like 
http://www.direct-optic.fr/essai-virtuel-lunettes-troisd/,that is to recognise eyes then generate glasses for user to see the Effect.
Currently I have down the first to recognise eyes using OpenCV2.4.1,but encounter a problem that I don't know how to use camera as a texture in OpenGL ES.
I have bulid the glass model using 3DMax with the format of .obj,trying to import it in OpenGL ES.
So I wonder if there is someone can give some demo of how to do it.
TI company have down it,but i don't know the details.
follow is the link:
http://www.t-immersion.com/trylive/trylive-eyewear.

Answer (score 0):

check out how the vuforia sample apps do it [here](https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/sdk/ios)

its an augmented reality api that uses the camera as a background texture